In ADF, I want to create a table in the sink with the primary key also created with the table. How can I do that?
Suppose I have a source table Table1 with PK as ID then how to create the same table in sink as Table1 with PK ID in it?
I want to create the table first through ADF then create primary key using a script in ADF itself and then ingest data from source to sink.
Tried running a pipeline but no keys were created but table was created and data was ingested.
